# How do I get a file from the Blobster API into a Foundry Transform?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

I'm using the Blobster API to get files from within a (e.g.) Python transform in Foundry Code Repositories or Foundry Code Workbooks.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: hi, did you ever find a solution for this? After adding the token to the url from the answer below I still get 404. As mentioned in the answer I get the multipass login html without it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `/blobster/api/salt/*rid***/token**`

If you use the endpoint sans `/token` with a classic `{... 'Authorization': auth_token header}` your request will return a redirect `(307)` response to the multipass login page. The response data will in fact be the html for the login page (probably not what you're after, nope, me neither).

Answer (score 0):

We had a use case to copy PDF files from a Compass folder to a dataset filesystem. I tried Andrew St P's answer but it did not work in our stack and returned a 404, assuming I understood it correctly to just append the token. This is what ended up working in our case, but I have no idea why, and this is completely undocumented. If anyone from Palantir is reading and has more insight feel free to comment!

```
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
import requests


 @transform(
     pdf=Output("OUT_PATH"),
 )
 def compute(pdf):

cookies = {
    'PALANTIR_TOKEN': 'AUTH_TOKEN',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://your-foundry-instance/blobster/api/salt/ri.blobster.main.pdf.0466bc73-fe31-40a2-89d0-536ecff719a3',
    cookies=cookies,
)
```